# Modifying Alpha in Unity Standard Shader

Tags: unity, shaders, cg, alpha

I'm trying to create a shader in Unity with a slider that can adjust the transparency. (This is the first step toward something more sophisticated.) I try to do this by setting the alpha of the SurfaceOutputStandard struct to the texture alpha times a value between 0 and 1:

```
Shader "Custom/MakeVisible" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _TransparencyMult ("Transparency Mulitplier", Range(0,1)) = 1
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;
        half _TransparencyMult;

        UNITY_INSTANCING_CBUFFER_START(Props)
        UNITY_INSTANCING_CBUFFER_END

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
            fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            o.Metallic = _Metallic;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;

            //Multiply alpha by value between 0 and 1
            o.Alpha = c.a * _TransparencyMult; 
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

This seems like it should work, since Alpha is an available property. But it doesn't. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I realized after reading closer that I needed to add the alpha:fade parameter for that to work, however, when I add that it is always transparent no matter what:

[image]

**EDIT:**
I changed the shader code according to Draco's answer:

```
Shader "Custom/MakeVisible" {
    Properties{
        _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _TransparencyMult("Transparency Mulitplier", Range(0,1)) = 1
        _MainTex("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { 
            "IgnoreProjector" = "True"
            "RenderType" = "Transparent"
            "Queue" = "Transparent"
        }
        LOD 200
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows alpha
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;
        half _TransparencyMult;

        UNITY_INSTANCING_CBUFFER_START(Props)
        UNITY_INSTANCING_CBUFFER_END

        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
            fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            o.Metallic = _Metallic;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;

            //Multiply alpha by value between 0 and 1
            o.Alpha = c.a * _TransparencyMult;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

Now it is always the same transparency with no texture:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to make 3 small changes to your shader:

1. You need to have the Queue properly set to Transparent or it won't render at all:

   ```
   Tags{
       "IgnoreProjector" = "True"
       "RenderType" = "Transparent"
       "Queue" = "Transparent"
   }
   ```
2. You need to set up a Blend Mode (this goes in the same place as Tags and LOD), if left out, this will be assumed (there are other blend modes):

   ```
   Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
   ```
3. You need to include the #pragma alpha in the #pragma declaration, this is what allows the alpha value to mean something:

   ```
   #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows alpha
   ```

Comment: If [`IgnoreProjector` tag](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SubShaderTags.html) is given and has a value of “True”, then an object that uses this shader will not be affected by Projectors. This is mostly useful on semitransparent objects, because there is no good way for Projectors to affect them.

Comment: I modified my shader, and now it's the same transparency no matter what. (I'll post an edit.)

Comment: @AaronF Compare with [this](https://pastebin.com/nKG0pYCE) which looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFKCG.png) with a color alpha value of 200 and a multiplier of 0.8

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure what's going on. I posted an edit with the results I got.

Comment: @AaronF Your color has the alpha pulled all the way down to 0.

Comment: Where? The slider is at 1. The texture isn't transparent.

Comment: My end goal is to have an object's material only be visible within a cone of light. To get there I first need to make a pbr surface shader use alpha, and then make that alpha depend on a world-position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68955/discussion-between-aaronf-and-draco18s).

Comment: So how did this ended up? I think I have the same problem: even if alpha is 0, something still renders (I think it's some shadow).

Comment: @Parziphal Make your own question. This one is over a year old and your problem might be different.

Comment: Yeah I know, I was just wondering about the conclusion of this. The chat is either inaccessible to me or deleted. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: @Parziphal Likely just inaccessible to you for some reason, I was able to view the archived chat history, which boils down to, essentially, "not your texture, [your color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BneDu.png)"